Insect Identification: Possible Flanged Bombardier Beetle Encounter
Location: Southern India
Insect Length ~ 1 cm
I encountered an insect in my room, and upon attempting to catch it, the insect released sharp, pungent vapor bursts repeatedly. The smell was extremely strong and long-lasting, to the point where I had to vacate the room for 30 minutes.
Using Google Lens, I got a suggestion that it could be a bombardier beetle (Platyrhopalopsis melleii). However, the pictures I found online don’t match exactly with the insect I encountered. I would appreciate help with the following:
1.  Can someone help identify this insect?
2.  What chemical did it release, and what are its effects on humans?
3.  What is that metallic stuff on its back?

warning: graphic images

 


 


The gold colour is part of its patternation, many beetles have irridescent colours, including some that appear almost all gold (such as the golden tortoise beetle. If you mean the silver under the elytra (wing cases), that's the wings.

While I am unsure of the exact species I am fairly sure it is some sort of ground beetle. The metallic stuff on it’s back is it’s hind wings
